# How to apply function of type A => Future[Try[Option[B]]] on given Future[Try[Option[A]]]?

Tags: scala, functional-programming, scalaz

I would like to simplify function application so that I could apply a function of type f: A => Future[Try[Option[B]]]  on element: Future[Try[Option[A]]]

In short, I need a definition for the below function :

```
def transformation(f: A => Future[Try[Option[B]]])
                       (element: Future[Try[Option[A]]]): Future[Try[Option[B]]] = ???
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because there are different monads involved and because of the fact that (as far as I know) there's no monad transformer for `Future[Try[Option]]]`, you need to map and match manually for each case:

```
def transformation[A, B](f: A => Future[Try[Option[B]]])(element: Future[Try[Option[A]]]): Future[Try[Option[B]]] = element.flatMap {
    case Success(Some(b)) => f(b)
    case Success(None) => Future.successful(Success(None))
    case Failure(fail) => Future.successful(Failure(fail))
}
```

Comment: Thanks this seems good...However its not able to infer type of innermost element...so for the line : case Success(Some(b)) => f(b) ...... it says type of b is Any.... but its not.

Comment: I don't know what you are doing but this compiles for me, note that I had to add the type A and B to the method definition because from your question they were nowhere to be seen.

Comment: @EndeNeu see my answer for a monad transformer equivalent to `Future[Try[Option]]]`.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to use **monad transformers**. Your type

```
Future[Try[Option[A]]]
```

is equivalent to

```
OptionT[EitherT[Future, Throwable, ?], A]
```

(The `?` syntax comes from the [`kind-projector`](https://github.com/non/kind-projector/) compiler plugin.)

Let's observe this step-by-step.

First, `Try[A]` is equivalent to a disjunction `Throwable \/ A` (where `\/` is just scalaz's equivalent of `Either`). We can translate between them via [`toDisjunction`, `fromDisjunction`](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/blob/d3d2f745a924d5da13721e74030b0a3233770cd3/core/src/main/scala/scalaz/std/Try.scala#L14-L18). This gives us that

```
Future[Try[Option[A]]]
```

is equivalent to

```
Future[Throwable \/ Option[A]]
```

Next, knowing that `F[A \/ B]` is the [definition](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/blob/06b8369f7d464c605695059131c0f7d15820fd66/core/src/main/scala/scalaz/EitherT.scala#L16) of `EitherT[F, A, B]`, we get that the above is equivalent to

```
EitherT[Future, Throwable, Option[A]]
```

Finally, noting that the [definition](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/blob/f53658f4f5218622949d1f72a32f1bf82c416e0b/core/src/main/scala/scalaz/OptionT.scala#L8) of `OptionT[F, A]` is `F[Option[A]]`, taking `F[?]` to be `EitherT[Future, Throwable, ?]` we conclude that the above is equivalent to

```
OptionT[EitherT[Future, Throwable, ?], A]
```

#### What do we gain by this representation?

Now your `transformation` function is just `flatMap`.

```
type Effect[A] = OptionT[EitherT[Future, Throwable, ?], A]

def transformation1[A, B](f: A => Effect[B])(element: Effect[A])
                         (implicit ec: ExecutionContext): Effect[B] =
  element.flatMap(f)
```

To obtain the `transformation` function with your original signature (i.e. the one that works with `Future[Try[Option[A]]]`), we need to define conversion methods to and from `Effect`.

```
def toEffect[A](a: Future[Try[Option[A]]])(implicit ec: ExecutionContext): Effect[A] = ???
def fromEffect[A](a: Effect[A])(implicit ec: ExecutionContext): Future[Try[Option[A]]] = ???

def transformation[A, B](f: A => Future[Try[Option[B]]])
                        (element: Future[Try[Option[A]]])
                        (implicit ec: ExecutionContext): Future[Try[Option[B]]] =
  fromEffect(for {
    a <- toEffect(element)
    b <- toEffect(f(a))
  } yield b)
```

But perhaps instead of converting back and forth you might want to use the monad transformer representation throughout your application.

#### Full Code

Here's the complete code, including imports. I tested it with scalaz 7.3.0-M10.

```
import scala.concurrent.{ExecutionContext, Future}
import scala.util.Try
import scalaz._
import scalaz.std.scalaFuture._
import scalaz.std.`try`._
import scalaz.syntax.std.`try`._

type Effect[A] = OptionT[EitherT[Future, Throwable, ?], A]

def toEffect[A](a: Future[Try[Option[A]]])(implicit ec: ExecutionContext): Effect[A] = {
  val b: Future[Throwable \/ Option[A]] = a.map(_.toDisjunction)
  val c: EitherT[Future, Throwable, Option[A]] = EitherT(b)
  val d: OptionT[EitherT[Future, Throwable, ?], A] = OptionT[EitherT[Future, Throwable, ?], A](c)
  d
}

def fromEffect[A](a: Effect[A])(implicit ec: ExecutionContext): Future[Try[Option[A]]] =
  a.run.run.map(fromDisjunction(_))

def transformation1[A, B](f: A => Effect[B])(element: Effect[A])
                         (implicit ec: ExecutionContext): Effect[B] =
  element.flatMap(f)

def transformation[A, B](f: A => Future[Try[Option[B]]])
                        (element: Future[Try[Option[A]]])
                        (implicit ec: ExecutionContext): Future[Try[Option[B]]] =
  fromEffect(for {
    a <- toEffect(element)
    b <- toEffect(f(a))
  } yield b)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, this also looks interesting. However, I am new to scalaz library. Could you please tell me best resource to learn scalaz for beginners with little or no FP background ?

Comment: This was me ~2-3 years ago. [Functional Programming in Scala](https://www.manning.com/books/functional-programming-in-scala) a.k.a. _the red book_ is a good introduction to FP in general (and happens to use Scala as the language). [Learning Scalaz](http://eed3si9n.com/learning-scalaz/index.html) is a good intro to Scalaz. After that you should be somewhat comfortable to just study scalaz code. It was frustrating at first that scalaz had almost no documentation, but then I realized that a lot of times the type signatures have all the information I need.

Comment: Thanks will surely have a look.

Answer (score 0):

If you've got to do something like this pretty often - you might consider using external libraries, like Emm+cats (or scalaz), basically they provide automatic monad transformers:

```
import $ivy.`org.typelevel::cats:0.9.0`
import $ivy.`com.codecommit::emm-core:0.2.1`
import $ivy.`com.codecommit::emm-cats:0.2.1`

import emm._
import scala.concurrent._
import scala.util._
import cats._
import emm.compat.cats._
import cats.implicits._
type E = Future |: Try |: Option |: Base
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global


def transformation[A, B](f: A => Future[Try[Option[B]]])
                       (element: Future[Try[Option[A]]]): Future[Try[Option[B]]] = {
  val effect: Emm[E, B] = for {
    elTry <- element.liftM[E]
    elOption <- elTry.liftM[E]
    el <- elOption.liftM[E]
    resTry <- f(el).liftM[E]
    resOption <- resTry.liftM[E]
    res <- resOption.liftM[E]
  } yield res    
  effect.run
}
```

Basically it's what you would do with `for` in normal case when monads have consistent types, just with a simple addition of `liftM`. Short version:

```
def transformation[A, B](f: A => Future[Try[Option[B]]])
                       (element: Future[Try[Option[A]]]): Future[Try[Option[B]]] = 
  element
    .liftM[E]
    .flatMap(_.liftM[E]).flatMap(_.liftM[E]) //unpack A
    .map(f) //apply transformation
    .flatMap(_.liftM[E]).flatMap(_.liftM[E]).flatMap(_.liftM[E]) //unpack B
    .run
```

Comment: what tool supports the '$ivy' syntax for imports?

Comment: @user2359636 ammonite shell, it works eithher as plugin for sbt or independent shell. And also scala kernel for jupyter notebook has modified version of ammonite - ammonium.